# ActionMailer deliver_later works in browser but not in test suite

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, minitest

I'm in the process of porting most of my mailers in my Rails 5 app to use deliver_later instead of deliver_now.

One of my mailers works just fine when I test it in the browser, but not when I run it in an integration test. (I've even started my rails server using my test environment and tested in the browser using the exact same data as my integration test, and it still runs fine in the browser, but the integration test fails).

The integration test is failing with the error:

> ERROR -- : Error performing ActionMailer::DeliveryJob (Job ID:
>   19b8c1c9-81e1-4209-b97b-0feb1e22fad3) from Async(mailers) in 65.64ms:
>   ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `message_text' for
>   nil:NilClass):

The line in my email template triggering the error is:
     `<p><%= simple_format(@message.message_text )%></p>`

I'm completely stumped figuring out why my @message object is nil when the mailer is called from an integration test but not in the browser.

Relevant code:

jobs_controller:

```
cj = ContactJob.create!(job_id: @job.id, contact_id: id, message:message)
...
cj.send_job_email
```

contact_job.rb:

```
class ContactJob < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :message
  belongs_to :contact
  belongs_to :job

  validates :contact, uniqueness: {scope: :job}
  validates :message, presence:true

  def send_job_email()
     ContactJobMailer.job(self.id).deliver_later
  end

end
```

contact_job_mailer.rb:

```
  def job (contact_job_id)
    @cj = ContactJob.find(contact_job_id)
    @contact=@cj.contact
    @job= @cj.job
    @message= @cj.message

    mail to: @contact.email, subject: 'test'
  end
```

integration test:

```
patch update_contacts_user_job_path(@user, @job), params: {job: {contact_ids: [ @contact2.id], message: {message_text: "This is a test"}}}
```

It's *only* the @message object that is nil, and only when I run it as part of an integration test, everything works fine in the browser.

Comment: do u have a running worker to handle the job ?

Comment: The email gets sent properly when I use the browser, so would seem  yes.

Comment: If I set "config.active_job.queue_adapter = :inline" into test.rb, I can get my integration test to pass, but 1) that's not what I want, and 2) still doesn't explain why the function works in my browser when the adapter is set to :async, but not in an integration test